# Anonymous std::packaged_task

Tags: c++, thread-safety, packaged-task

i am trying to build some wrapper around Glib::Dispatcher to dispatch any functional type into the dispatcher. I want to have some function dispatch that can transfer a function into the Glib main loop:

```
template<class Function, class ...Args>
std::future<typename std::result_of<Function(Args...)>::type>
dispatch(Function &&f, Args &&...args);
```

This function would create a packaged task from f(args) and return its future:

```
std::packaged_task<typename std::result_of<Function(Args...)>::type()> task(f(args...));
return task.get_future();
```

I need to create now from this task a `std::packaged_task<void()>` to put them into one std::queue so that the connected function to Glib::Dispatcher can execute them.

My question is: How can i create from a `std::packaged_task<R()>` a `std::packaged_task<void()>` in two steps, so that i can return from the first task its future and put the second one into a queue of `std::queue<std::packaged_task<void()>>` type?

Comment: It also can be of other functor type instead of `std::packaged_task<void()>`; They all just have to hide `f` and `args...`.

Comment: I have found a way to implement that using type erasure, but is there some way to use the stl for my problem?

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, to have `std::packaged_task` invoke a particular function with a given argument set then either (a) you need to bind the function to the arguments before you pass it to `std::packaged_task`, or (b) you need to pass the arguments to the function call operator of the `std::packaged_task` object. In your code, you are passing `f(args...)` to the `std::packaged_task` constructor, which will call the function right there and then pass the result to the constructor, which is probably not what you want and may not even compile.

Secondly, if you bind the arguments at construction time then your `std::packaged_task` instance is a callable object that takes no parameters and returns `void`, so can be *moved* directly into a `std::packaged_task<void()>`.

Putting this all together, we get:

```
std::queue<std::packaged_task<void()>> task_queue;

template<class Function, class ...Args>
std::future<typename std::result_of<Function(Args...)>::type>
dispatch(Function &&f, Args &&...args) {
    std::packaged_task<typename std::result_of<Function(Args...)>::type()> task(
        std::bind(f,args...));
    auto res=task.get_future();
    task_queue.push(std::packaged_task<void()>(std::move(task)));
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work with Microsoft's STL https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/108672/unable-to-move-stdpackaged-task-into-any-stl-conta.html

Comment: It's old question. But i decided write how works
std::packaged_task<void()>(std::move(task))   expression since C++17.

if result_of <function> - is void -- it simply moved.

otherweice it calls template<typename Func> packaged_task(Func&&) constructor, where Func=std::packaged_task<non_void_return_type()> .  

In practise  packaged_task - is std::shared_ptr < ...> ,  and second case there allocated shared_ptr< shared_ptr < ... > >   :)